How to add element in Django QuerySet?
I have model Report and GroupReport. They have many-to-many relation.
I can easily get QuerySet[GroupReport] for all GroupReport instance:
  Group Name 1:
    Report Name 1
    Report Name 2
  Group Name 2:
    Report Name 2
    Report Name 10
  ... and etc.

But i need to add entry "Total Reports" to QuerySet[GroupReport]:
  Group All reports:
    Report Name 1
    Report Name 2
    Report Name 5
  ... and another reports from QuerySet[Report]

I can't store group "Total Reports" in database because using object permissions for QuerySets. It is necessary to generate the group dynamically. My Serializer expect correct queryset.
How can i do this?
I tried to do it something like this:
def get_queryset(self):
  groups = get_objects_for_user(
    user=self.request.user,
    perms=view_reportgroup,
    klass=ReportGroup.actived_objects,
    accept_global_perms=False
  )
  reports = get_objects_for_user(
    user=self.request.user,
    perms=view_report,
    klass=Report.actived_objects,
    accept_global_perms=False
  )
  total = ReportStorage(id=None, name='Total Reports')
  total.reports.set(
    Report.actived_objects.filter(
      Q(id__in=reports) | Q(groups__in=groups)
    ).distinct()
  )
  return (groups | total).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
      'reports',
      queryset=ReportStorage.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
          'reportstorage',
          queryset=super().get_queryset()
        )
      )
    )
  )

But got expected error: "needs to have a value for field 'id' bla-bla..." for total.reports.set.
I was also thinking about adding ReportStorage to groups._result_cache. But I don't understand how it should look. Maybe there are more correct ways such as custom SQL, converting QuerySet to List?
ViewSets:
class ReportStorageGenericViewSet(GenericViewSet):
    """
    Basic view for filtering file storage objects.

    Fields
    -------
    queryset: QuerySet[ReportStorage]
        Basic set of objects.
    query_params_validator: QueryParamValidator
        Class for processing the correctness of the specified date from query_param.
    """
    queryset = ReportStorage.objects
    query_params_validator = QueryParamsValidator()  # getattr(settings, 'DATE_INPUT_FORMATS', None))
    permission_classes = [PortalRDjangoObjectPermissions]

    def _get_date(self) -> date:
        """
        Getting date from query_params.

        :return: Valid date, if the value is not specified, the reporting day is used.
        """
        date_str = self.request.query_params.get('date')
        self.query_params_validator(date_str)
        if date_str:
            return parse_date(date_str)

        return (timezone.now() - timedelta(days=1)).date()

    def get_queryset(self) -> QuerySet[ReportStorage]:
        """
        Generating a list of objects.

        It is guaranteed that the list of files is filtered by date.

        :return: A set of ReportStorage objects.
        """
        return super().get_queryset().filter(validity_period__contains=self._get_date())

    def get_serializer_context(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        """
        Adding a queryset to the context during the List operation to further check for the presence of loaded help at the current time.

        :return: Context for the serializer.
        """
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        if self.action == 'list':
            context['queryset'] = self.get_queryset()

        return context

    def handle_exception(self, exc: APIException) -> Response:
        """
        Handling request execution errors.

        :param exc: Query execution exception.
        :return: If an error occurs, returns a standard {"detail": "message"} JSON response.
        """
        if isinstance(exc, ValidationError):
            return Response({"detail": exc.detail}, status=exc.status_code)

        return super().handle_exception(exc=exc)

class ReportGroupViewSet(ListModelMixin, ReportStorageGenericViewSet):
    """
    View to get a list of reporting groups with enabled reports and file uploads.

    Fields
    -------
    serializer_class: ReportGroupSerializer
        Basic view object serializer.
    """
    serializer_class = ReportGroupSerializer

    def get_queryset(self) -> QuerySet[ReportGroup]:
        """
        Generating a list of objects.

        :return: List of ReportGroup objects.
        """
        #### Override queryset here ####
        return ReportGroup.actived_objects.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                'reports',
                queryset=Report.actived_objects.prefetch_related(
                    Prefetch('storage', queryset=super().get_queryset())
                )
            )
        )


So this is a APIView or ViewSet, or something similar?

Can you share the vieset? Does it do any extra filtering/searching/whatever?

@willeM_VanOnsem, Its's ViewSet. Post updated

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I added "total group" in database and set all reports to it.
Queryset fixed:
def _get_accessible_reports(self, perms: str | List[str]) -> QuerySet[Report]:
  """
  Method for obtaining a list of reports available to the user.

  :param perms: list of rights in a standard name, for example: 'add', 'change', 'delete', 'view'.
                You can check the available actions in Meta[default_permissions, permissions]: Report | ReportGroup.
  :return: Complete list of reports that the user has access to directly or through reporting groups.
  """
  if self.request.user.is_superuser:
      return Report.actived_objects.all()

  if isinstance(perms, str):
      perms = [perms]

  reports = get_objects_for_user(
      user=self.request.user,
      perms=[f'{perm}_report' for perm in perms],
      klass=Report.actived_objects,
      any_perm=True,
      accept_global_perms=False
  )
  groups = get_objects_for_user(
      user=self.request.user,
      perms=[f'{perm}_reportgroup' for perm in perms],
      klass=ReportGroup.actived_objects,
      any_perm=True,
      accept_global_perms=False
  )

  return Report.actived_objects.filter(
      Q(id__in=reports) | Q(groups__in=groups)
  ).distinct()


def get_queryset(self):
  """
  Generating a list of objects.

  return: List of ReportGroup objects.
  """
  total_reports = self._get_accessible_reports('view')
        return ReportGroup.actived_objects.filter(reports__in=total_reports).distinct().prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                'reports',
                queryset=Report.actived_objects.filter(id__in=total_reports).prefetch_related(
                    Prefetch(
                        'storage',
                        queryset=super().get_queryset()
                    )
                )
            )
        )


